# migration from s3 to google cloud storage and ACL

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am currently planning a possible migration from s3 to google cloud storage(g-c-s). I have decided to spin up a gce instance and use gsutil to rsync several millions of files. I would like to know if the permission will be preserved or not. 
for example if a file has public read on amazon s3 what will be the acl on g-c-s.
thanks

Comment: If you have millions of large files that you would like to import from S3, you may want to request access to the beta "Online Cloud Import" service: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/online-cloud-import

Answer (score 2):

If you use the gsutil cp command you can specify a canned ACL on the command line, like this:

```
gsutil cp -R -a public-read s3://your-s3-bucket gs://your-gs-bucket
```

The rsync command doesn't have a way to do that. However, the other option is you can set a default object ACL on the destination bucket, using the gsutil defacl command. Then you can use gsutil cp without specifying the canned ACL, or you could use gsutil rsync.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It's great that i can specify a canned acl but what I actually want is to replicate the current acl specified for my objects. is there a feature like that ?

Comment: You can use the cp -p option (or rsync -p option) to do that.

Comment: Note that the cp -p option only works within the same storage provider - S3 ACLs don't map one-to-one with GCS ACLs.